# Solving $\sin\theta -1=\cos\theta $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve$$\sin\theta -1=\cos\theta $$

Steps I took to solve this:

$$\sin^{ 2 }\theta -2\sin\theta +1=1-\sin^2\theta $$

$$2\sin^{ 2 }\theta -2\sin\theta =0$$

$$(2\sin\theta )(\sin\theta -1)=0$$

$$2\sin\theta =0, \sin\theta -1=0$$

$$\quad \sin\theta =0, \sin\theta =1$$

$$\theta =0+\pi k, \theta =\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } +2\pi k$$

Why is $\theta =0+\pi k$ wrong?

Comment: i think the reason is that you have squared the equation

Comment: If $k$ is odd $\pi k$ is solution.

Comment: For even $k$, if your try $0+\pi k$ in the original equation, you have $-1=1$, which is false. But because your process started off by squaring both sides, this is lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you square both sides of an equation, you may introduce extraneous solutions.  Therefore, you must check that your solutions satisfy the original equations (a good idea in any case).

When you squared the equation $\sin\theta - 1 = \cos\theta$, you discovered that 
the resulting equation was satisfied when $\sin\theta = 0$ or $\sin\theta = 1$.

In the interval $[0, 2\pi)$, the equation $\sin\theta = 0$ is satisfied when $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = \pi$.  If $\theta = 0$, then

$$\sin(0) - 1 = 0 - 1 = -1 \neq 1 = \cos(0)$$

so $0$ is an extraneous solution.  On the other hand, if $\theta = \pi$, then

$$\sin(\pi) - 1 = 0 - 1 = -1 = \cos(\pi)$$

so $\theta = \pi$ is a valid solution.

In the interval $[0, 2\pi)$, the equation $\sin\theta = 1$ is satisfied when $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.  When $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$,

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0 = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Thus, $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ is a valid solution.

Thus, the general solution of the equation $\sin\theta - 1 = \cos\theta$ is

$$
\theta = 
\begin{cases}
\pi + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\dfrac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

by squaring both sides you are getting a solution set which is bigger than original problem

for example if $x^2=1$ both $x=-1$ and $1$ are solutions but you only want one of them

Comment: So how do I know which one to choose? Sorry, I'm drawing a blank here.

Comment: honestly i wouldn't use this method at all as its not best practice and leads to inconsistency I would use a method of compound wave function method if you know that

Comment: I'm afraid I don't.

Comment: Let $sin\theta-cos\theta=1$ and consider $sin(\theta-x)$  and expand it equate like terms and solve for it. If you still stuck type wave function solution on youtube.

Comment: if u still want this method let me know i will get u a link

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/higher/maths/trigonometry/wave_function/revision/1/

Comment: Couldn't I have just entered the solutions back in the original equation and seen which one is the actual solution?

Comment: you could in this instance but i wouldn't recommend it as a technique in the long run

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta)&=1\\
\sin(\theta)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\cos(\theta)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\sin(\theta)\sin(\pi/4)-\cos(\theta)\cos(\pi/4)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
-\cos(\theta+\pi/4)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\cos(\theta+\pi/4)&=-{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\\
\theta+\pi/4&=(2k+1)\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\theta&=(2k+3/4)\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\theta&=(2k+1/2)\pi\qquad\text{or}\qquad(2k+1)\pi
\end{align}$$

Thinking of the unit circle as a compass, these solutions are "north" and "west".

Comment: Your first answer is extraneous. No?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer No step of the above introduced any extraneous solutions. Loosely, the first solution is north, and the second is west. $\sin(\text{north})-1=\cos(\text{north})\implies1-1=0\checkmark$ And $\sin(\text{west})-1=\cos(\text{west})\implies0-1=-1\checkmark$.

Comment: Alternatively, you could replace $\sin\theta\sin\left(\frac{pi}{4}\right) - \cos\theta\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ with $\sin\left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ to obtain the equation $\sin\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  In any case, it is a nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid squaring as reasoned by N. F. Taussig.

$$\sin\theta=1+\cos\theta$$

Using double angle formulae,

$$2\sin\dfrac\theta2\cos\dfrac\theta2-2\cos^2\dfrac\theta2=0$$

$$\iff2\cos\dfrac\theta2\left(\sin\dfrac\theta2-\cos\dfrac\theta2\right)=0$$

Now the product of two terms is zero,

If $\cos\dfrac\theta2=0,\dfrac\theta2=(2n+1)\dfrac\pi2\iff\theta=(2n+1)\pi$

Else $\sin\dfrac\theta2-\cos\dfrac\theta2=0\iff\sin\dfrac\theta2=\cos\dfrac\theta2\iff\tan\dfrac\theta2=1$

Now if $\tan x=\tan A,x=m\pi+A$

where $m,n$ are arbitrary integer

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\sin(\theta)=2\,{\frac {\tan \left( \theta/2 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( \theta
/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$
and $$\cos(\theta)={\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( \theta/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+
 \left( \tan \left( \theta/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$