# Solving $\cos\theta \cos3\theta -\sin\theta \sin3\theta =0$ , $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\cos\theta \cos3\theta -\sin\theta \sin3\theta =0$$

I know that this uses the cosine addition formula and could be rewritten as $\cos(\theta +3\theta )=0$

and then as $\cos(4\theta )=0$ However , I don't know where to go from here. I'd like to be guided so that I can possibly arrive at the correct answer by myself.

Answer (score 5):

$$\cos4\theta=0\implies4\theta=(2n+1)\frac\pi2,\theta=(2n+1)\frac\pi8$$ where $n$ is any integer

We need $0\le(2n+1)\dfrac\pi8<2\pi \implies0\le2n+1<16\implies n=? $

Comment: $cos(4\theta )=0$, so $4\theta =\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } +2\pi k$
So now I divide it by $4$ to get $\theta $ itself. This comes out to $4\theta =\frac { \pi  }{ 8 } +\frac { 2\pi k }{ 4 } $ 
And now I just add right before I reach a full rotation?

Comment: yep, starting with k=0, then k=1, etc

Comment: When I add it the first time, I already reach $\frac { 5\pi  }{ 8 } $, yet $\frac { 3\pi  }{ 8 }$ should be a solution

Comment: @Alan, $2n<15\implies n<7.5\implies n\le7$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee aren't some of those solutions extraneous?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, We need $0\le2n+1<16\implies0\le n\le7$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Ok and then what do I do with those values

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, Not sure about your future activity!  We have $$\theta=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}8$$ where $0\le n\le7$

Comment: My future activity? This made no sense to me because I haven't come across any other examples that solve it this way. I was able to solve it using the method I put in my first comment. And then I realized that extraneous solutions didn't matter because it asked for "all" solutions.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057685/solving-sin-theta-1-cos-theta/1058809#1058809 and many others : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry

Comment: @Cherry_Developer $$\cos(4\theta) = 0 \Rightarrow 4\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$ so you should obtain $$\theta = \frac{\pi}{8} + k\frac{\pi}{4}$$ which is equivalent to the correct answer provided by lab bhattacharjee.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I got the same answer. The only reason I was wrong at first was because I thought I should leave out extraneous solutions.