# Solving $\cos x+\sin x-1=0$

Tags: trigonometry

How does one solve this equation?

> $$\cos {x}+\sin {x}-1=0$$

I have no idea how to start it.

Can anyone give me some hints? Is there an identity for $\cos{x}+\sin{x}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding 1 to both sides. Then square both sides. From there, you'll spot some identities. Be wary of any extraneous solutions that could arise.

Comment: @Mathxx, Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057685/solving-sin-theta-1-cos-theta/1058809#1058809

Comment: You can solve $a\sin x+b\cos x-c=0$ in general: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213545/solving-trigonometric-equations-of-the-form-a-sin-x-b-cos-x-c

Comment: I think its not identity. Its an equation which you want to solve for $x$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rewrite as:

$$\cos(x)+\sin(x)=1$$
Then square:
$$\cos^2(x)+2\cos(x)\sin(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$$
Note an important identity:
$$1+2\cos(x)\sin(x)=1$$
Then simplify and note another identity:
$$\sin(2x)=0$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Someone downvoted every answer in this question.

Comment: Down voters need to be neutralized.  +1 for this solid answer.

Comment: fwiw you can skip the last identify and go for $\cos x = 0$ or $\sin x = 0$.

Answer (score 17):

Given $$\color{blue}{\cos x+\sin x-1=0} $$$$\cos x+\sin x=1 $$ Divide both sides by $\color{blue}{\sqrt{2}}$ we get $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos x+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ $$\cos x\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+\sin x\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$$ Using formula $\color{purple}{\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B=\cos(A-B)}$, we get $$\color{green}{\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}}$$ As there is no information about the unknown value $x$ hence writing the general solutions as follows $$x-\frac{\pi}{4}=2n\pi\pm \frac{\pi}{4}$$$$x=2n\pi\pm \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$$$ \color{}{x=2n\pi} \quad \text{Or}\quad \color{}{x=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}} $$ 
$$\color{blue}{x\in\{2n\pi\}\cup\{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\}}$$ Where, $\color{}{n \space \text{is any integer}}$ i.e. $\ n=0, \pm1, \pm2,\pm3, \ldots$

Answer (score 9):

As $\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)$ by the angle addition formula we find that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\cos x+\sin x-1&=0\\
\implies\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)&=1\\
\implies\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\implies x+\frac{\pi}{4}&=\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi n,\frac{3\pi}{4}+2\pi n\\
\implies x&=2\pi n,\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 7):

$\cos x+\sin x=\sqrt2\cos\Bigl(x-\dfrac\pi4\Bigr)$, hence the equation is equivalent to:
$$\cos\Bigl(x-\frac\pi4\Bigr)=\frac1{\sqrt2}\iff x-\frac\pi4\equiv\pm\frac\pi4\mod 2\pi\iff x\equiv 0,\,\frac\pi2\mod2\pi.$$

Answer (score 4):

you can use: $$ \cos(x)= \sqrt{1-\sin(x)^{2}}$$  $$ \text{then let}\qquad  \sin(x)=t\\
\sqrt{1-t^{2}}+t-1=0$$ now you can continue

Comment: And what about the cases where $\cos x \neq \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$ ?

Comment: $$
in \;this \;case \;: cos(x)=-\sqrt{1-sin(x)}\leq 0\\but :cos(x)=1-sin(x)\leq 0\; so \;cos(x)=0\\in \; this \; case \; \sqrt{1-sin(x)}=-\sqrt{1-sin(x)}=0
$$

Comment: Did you know that your answer can contain text that is no between \$...\$?

Comment: yes i knew that $_$

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw my hat in the ring to get a picture in edgewise. :-)

[image]

I'll use $\theta$ for the angle, rather than $x$ (to avoid confusion with the $x$-coordinate).  If we then let $x = \cos \theta, y = \sin \theta$, then the allowable results are along the red circle with $x^2+y^2 = 1$ (since $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$).  The solutions of the given equation are at the intersections of the blue line $x+y = 1$ with that red circle, yielding $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = (1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$.

This in turn yields

$$
\theta = 2k\pi, \qquad \theta = 2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

for $k$ an integer.

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, it is obvious, that: $1-\sin{x} \equiv (\cos{\frac{x}{2}} - \sin{\frac{x}{2}})^2$.

From the half angle expansions, $\cos{x} \equiv (\cos{\frac{x}{2}} - \sin{\frac{x}{2}})(\cos{\frac{x}{2}} + \sin{\frac{x}{2}})$.

The equation is thus equivalent to:

$(\cos{\frac{x}{2}} - \sin{\frac{x}{2}})(2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}) = 0$

Which can then be solved using standard methods.

Answer (score 0):

starting from, $$\cos x+\sin x-1=0$$ $$(\sin x+\cos x)^2=1^2$$ completing square, i get $$\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x+2\sin \cos x=1$$ $$1+\sin 2x=1$$$$\sin 2x=0$$
$$2x=k\pi$$
$$x=\frac{k\pi}{2}$$ where, $k=0, \pm 1, \pm2, \ldots$

Comment: $\equiv$ Zachary Selk's answer?

Comment: $x=k\pi/2$ is not a solution to $\cos x+\sin x-1=0$ when $k=2$.  Or $3$.