# $\sin(2x)-\cos(2x)-\sin(x)+\cos(x)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to share a trigonometry question here. Wonder is there another way to solve it or not.

$\sin(2x)-\cos(2x)-\sin(x)+\cos(x)=0$

$2\cos(x)\sin(x)-(1-2\sin^2(x))-\sin(x)+\cos(x)=0$

$2\cos(x)\sin(x)-1+2\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)+\cos(x)=0$

$2\sin^2(x)+2\cos(x)\sin(x)-\sin(x)+\cos(x)-1=0$

$(2\sin(x)+1)(\sin(x)+\cos(x)-1)=0$

So, we have $$2\sin(x)+1=0 \space\text{and}\sin(x)+\cos(x)-1=0$$

$2\sin(x)+1=0$

$\sin(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$

$x=\frac{7\pi}{6}+2\pi n,\frac{11\pi}{6}+2\pi n$

$\sin(x)+\cos(x)-1=0$ which answered in my yesterday post [$\cos x+\sin x=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307085/cos-x-sin-x-1-0-identity)

and get $x=2n\pi,2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$

Combine all the solutions, $$x=2\pi n,x=\frac{7\pi}{6}+2\pi n,x=2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{2}, x=\frac{11\pi}{6}+2\pi n$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\cos A-\sin A=\cos B-\sin B$

As $\cos A-\sin A=\cdots=\sqrt2\cos\left(A+\dfrac\pi4\right),$

$\cos\left(A+\dfrac\pi4\right)=\cos\left(B+\dfrac\pi4\right)$

$\implies A+\dfrac\pi4=2m\pi\pm\left(B+\dfrac\pi4\right)$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: The given answer is  $2n \pi$ and $(4n-1)\cdot\frac{\pi}{6}$ Why?
Am I wrong?

Comment: @Mathxx, Put $n=3m,3m+1,3m+2$ in $\dfrac{(4n-1)\pi}6$

Answer (score 0):

If $\sin2A-\sin2B=\cos2A-\cos2B$

using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas, $$2\sin(A-B)\cos(A+B)=-2\sin(A-B)\sin(A+B)$$

$$2\sin(A-B)[\cos(A+B)+\sin(A+B)]=0$$

$\sin(A-B)=0\implies A-B=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

$\cos(A+B)+\sin(A+B)=0\iff\tan(A+B)=-1=\tan\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)$

$A+B=m\pi-\dfrac\pi4$  where $m$ is any integer