# General solution of $x$ if $\sin x+\cos x=1$

Tags: trigonometry

General solution to the equation $\sin x+\cos x$=$1$ is found to be $x=2n\pi$ and $x=2n\pi+\pi/2$, Pls refer [Solving cosx+sinx−1=0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307085/solving-cos-x-sin-x-1-0)

**My Approach:**
$$
\sin x+\cos x=1\implies \sin x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cos x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\implies\sin x\cos(\pi/4)+\cos x\sin(\pi/4)=\sin(\pi/4)\implies \sin(x+\pi/4)=\sin(\pi/4)\implies x+\pi/4=n\pi+(-1)^n
[\pi/4]\implies x=n\pi+(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
How do I check both the results are the same, without inputting the values for $n$ ?

Comment: What happened to the second solution to the quadratic? Have you potentially divided by zero?

Comment: By the way, this isn't a duplicate, because it is asking about a potential error in a method not exemplified in the linked question or its answers.

Comment: your second approach doesn't seem to have $x = 0$ as a solution.  So, something must have dropped.

Comment: $$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt 2(\sin x\cos 45^{\circ}+\cos x\sin 45^{\circ}=\sqrt 2\sin(45^{\circ}+x)=1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the formulas with $\tan(x/2)$ only for the values where it is defined, which excludes $x=\pi+2k\pi$. If the equation has this value as a solution, you'll lose it (but of course you can check for it at the outset).

This is not the case for your equation. Instead you pass from
$$
2\tan\frac{x}{2}+1-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}=1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}
$$
to
$$
2\tan\frac{x}{2}\left(\tan\frac{x}{2}-1\right)=0
$$
to
$$
\tan\frac{x}{2}-1=0
$$
forgetting the possibility that $\tan\frac{x}{2}=0$.

This would be like saying that the equation $2x^2-2x=0$ has only the solution $x=1$, forgetting $x=0$.

Comment: thnx. if I substitute in terms of $\tan(x/2)$ for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, which gives $x=2k\pi$ and $2k\pi+\pi/2$ as general solutions of the equation. My doubt is how do we properly compare with the form $x=k\pi+(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}$ ?

Comment: @ss1729 If $k=2n$ is even, then $k\pi+(-1)^k\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}=2n\pi$; if $k=2n+1$ is odd, then $k\pi+(-1)^k\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$. That way of expressing solutions is tricky and useless.

Comment: thanks...that solves my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

$${\color{Red}{a \sin x+ b \cos x=c \\ \frac{|a|}{a} \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin (x+\alpha)=c\\ \tan \alpha=\frac{b}{a}}  }$$ 
$$ \sin \theta +\cos\theta=1\\ \sin \theta +\cos\theta=\frac{|+1|}{+1}\sqrt{2} \sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})= \\\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})  \\\sqrt{2} \sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})=1$$ so $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x+\frac{\pi}{4}=+\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi\\ 
x+\frac{\pi}{4}=\pi-(+\frac{\pi}{4})+2k\pi
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Answer (score 0):

Summary:
The solutions are
$x=2j\pi$ and
$x=2j\pi+\pi/2$
for any integer $j$.
The first of each set
is
$x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$.

Note:
In what follows, $k$ and $j$
are integers.

Squaring
$\sin x+\cos x=1$,
$1 
=\sin^2 x + 2\sin x \cos x+\cos^2 x
=1+ 2\sin x \cos x
$
so
$0
=2\sin x \cos x
=\sin(2x)
$
so that
$2x = k\pi$
or
$x = k\pi/2
$.

To see which
extra solutions were
introduced by squaring,
if
$x = k\pi/2
$
then
$\sin x
=0
$
if $k$ is even
and
$(-1)^{(k-1)/2}
$
if $k$ is odd;
$\cos x
=0
$
if $k$ is odd
and
$(-1)^{k/2}
$
if $k$ is even.

For even $k$,
we want
$(-1)^{k/2} = 1$,
so $k/2$ is even
so $k = 4j$
and
$x = 2j \pi$.

For odd $k$,
we want
$(-1)^{(k-1)/2}
= 1$
so
$(k-1)/2 = 2j$
so $k = 4j+1$
and
$x = (4j+1)\pi/2
=(2j+1/2)\pi
=2 j \pi+\pi/2
$.